# Python regex removing non alpha numeric characters from string except brackets

Tags: python, regex

I have the following regex , which remove all no alpha numeric characters from a string text

```
re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9]',' ', text)
```

How can I modify this expression to include the characters '[' and ']' in the string text ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `[`, `]` to the charcter class (`[ .. ]`) with escaping.

```
re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9\[\]]',' ', text)
```

Example:

```
>>> re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9\[\]]', ' ', 'a,b[c-d]!')
'a b[c d] '
```